# Modifying list with user input in python

Tags: python

I was wondering how I could take this user input(below) and just modify the item that is already in the list. If the user does not input the same item as show in the list then just add the input as a new grocery item.

**List**

```
inventory = [['Milk,   3.99,  25'],
             ['Bread,  1.99,  35'],
             ['Eggs,   1.99,  50'],
             ['Flour,  0.52,  20'],
             ['Rice,   0.72,  35']]
```

**Input**

```
modItem = input("Enter the name of an existing item you want to modify:")
modPrice = input("Enter the new price of the item:")
modStock = input("Enter the new stock of the item:")
inventory.append([modItem, modPrice, modStock])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried?  Do you know how to iterate over a list?  Just take the problem step by step.

Comment: So far it takes the user input and puts it into the list, but I wanted to find out how the program can just modify the price and stock if the user inputs the same item name as shown in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the item already exists using a simple function:

```py
def check_inventory(modItem, inventory):
 try:
   for item in inventory:
      if modItem == item[0].split(', ')[0]:
         return True
   
 except:
   pass

 return False


...

# then, you can call your function 
if (check_inventory(modItem, inventory)):
    inventory.append([modItem, modPrice, modStock])
```

The second approach is converting your list into a dict. I would recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict

```
inventory = {'Milk': [3.99,  25],
             'Bread':  [1.99,  35],
             'Eggs':  [1.99,  50],
             'Flour': [0.52,  20],
             'Rice': [0.72,  35]}

modItem = input("Enter the name of an existing item you want to modify:")
modPrice = float(input("Enter the new price of the item:"))
modStock = int(input("Enter the new stock of the item:"))

Enter the name of an existing item you want to modify:Milk
Enter the new price of the item:10
Enter the new stock of the item:12
```

If item already exists, it will be replaced, else a new key-value pair would be added

```
inventory[modItem] =  [modPrice, modStock]

inventory

{'Milk': [10.0, 12],
 'Bread': [1.99, 35],
 'Eggs': [1.99, 50],
 'Flour': [0.52, 20],
 'Rice': [0.72, 35]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `inventory` list was malformed.  Here's code that does what you want in the most direct way, given your existing code and the corrected version of your data:

```
inventory = [['Milk', '3.99',  '25'],
             ['Bread',  '1.99',  '35'],
             ['Eggs',   '1.99',  '50'],
             ['Flour',  '0.52',  '20'],
             ['Rice',   '0.72',  '35']]

modItem = input("Enter the name of an existing item you want to modify:")
modPrice = input("Enter the new price of the item:")
modStock = input("Enter the new stock of the item:")

for item in inventory:
    if item[0] == modItem:
        item[1] = modPrice
        item[2] = modStock
        break
else:
    inventory.append([modItem, modPrice, modStock])
```

This code loops over the existing inventory, looking for the item the user entered the name of.  If the name is found, the item containing that item is updated with the new price and quantity.  If no existing item is found, then a new item is created and added.

Comment: @Rajesh - Greetings.  I am wondering if my answer to your question was helpful.  Did it answer your question?  If so, I encourage you to upvote it and/or accept it as the correct answer via the checkmark button.  Note that you get points for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate` and modify the list while iterating over the elements:

```
inventory = [['Milk,   3.99,  25'],
             ['Bread,  1.99,  35'],
             ['Eggs,   1.99,  50'],
             ['Flour,  0.52,  20'],
             ['Rice,   0.72,  35']]

modItem = 'Milk' 
modPrice = 4
modStock = 30

found = False
for idx, elt in enumerate(inventory):
    if modItem in elt[0]:
        inventory[idx] = [f"{modItem}, {modPrice}, {modStock}"] # modify the element at the found index
        found = True
        break

if not found:
        inventory.append([f"{modItem}, {modPrice}, {modStock}"])
print(inventory)
```

Output:

```
[['Milk, 4, 30'], ['Bread,  1.99,  35'], ['Eggs,   1.99,  50'], ['Flour,  0.52,  20'], ['Rice,   0.72,  35']]
```

Further, I would suggest to keep the inner list as the list of elements. Currently, it is just a single element with a `str` object.

```
inventory = [['Milk', 3.99, 25],
             ['Bread', 1.99, 35],
             ['Eggs', 1.99, 50],
             ['Flour', 0.52, 20],
             ['Rice', 0.72, 35]]

found = False
for idx, elt in enumerate(inventory):
    if modItem == elt[0]:
        inventory[idx] = [modItem, modPrice, modStock]
        found = True
        break

if not found:
    inventory.append([modItem, modPrice, modStock])
print(inventory)
```

Output:

```
[['Milk', 4, 30], ['Bread', 1.99, 35], ['Eggs', 1.99, 50], ['Flour', 0.52, 20], ['Rice', 0.72, 35]]
```